# change EF STE to wcf data service

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, windows-services, dataservice

I have a WCF class library that I host it with a **Windows Service** on an address like this (`http://myIPAdress:port/MyService`).

The WCFclass library has BLL(business) reference and Common(Types) reference and BLL has DAL reference (n-tier) in DAL I have an EF DB with **STE generator** (types generate in Common). And my client application is a WPF with my service reference (works with Internet).

As I read in this site [STE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613924.aspx) the STE is not recommended any more and I decied use WCF **data service**. I just send EF class over the service and updating is a pain.

Now my questions are:

1. Is it good idea to change STE to data service? If no, what is best idea? I hate STE!
2. How can I change it with less effort?
3. If I have a data service can I host it with a Windows Service or better host it with one Windows Service? (I mean merge it with main WCF service)
4. How much secure is data service? I mean can I encrypt my data etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answers for just 2 of the questions, but maybe some other people will guide more with complete answers.

**Question 3.** You can host any WCF service implementation with a Windows Service (meaning you can self-host any WCF service).
Quote from MSDN:

> Because it incorporates a WCF implementation, WCF Data Services
>   support self-hosting a data service as a WCF service. A service can be
>   self-hosted in any .NET Framework application, such as a console
>   application. The DataServiceHost class, which inherits from
>   WebServiceHost, is used to instantiate the data service at a specific
>   address.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668805.aspx

**Question 4.** Any service/application you develop is as secure you code it, host it or use it. And your service is as unsecure as your most unsecure component.
A Data Service can be made secure if properly implemented and configurated. You can also use secured bindings and so on.
MSDN is again your friend with guideliness for Data Service security
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728284.aspx

But keep in mind that IIS allows you more configurations for many things, including security, than self-hosting (using Windows Service).

Comment: thanks for usefull answer and links. if no other answer this will be best answer. i have another question ... what is the goal of data service . i mean is it good for my project ? (my application is a server-client app that server has a windows service and client will connect to it with username and pass then insert / update / delete / report data) now what is better poco or ste or data service or even ef code first ?